# Trying to get relationships with unique endpoints from Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes present in the graph like this:

```
(A)-[relationship1]->(object)-[relationship2]->(B)
```

Searching for this brings up 1000s of matches.
What I'm trying to get is return (A) when number of UNIQUE Bs is greater than 25.

Comment: Can you post your search query ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any error on your query?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in Cypher, you can use 'WITH'. This is a very useful resource to help understand cypher: [cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/)

The "WITH" works like a "RETURN" and calculates the cypher preceding it, allowing you then to work on the output of that in a another step in the cypher. This is how you can use it to achieve your result:

```
MATCH (A)-[:RELATIONSHIP1_TYPE]->(obj)-[:RELATIONSHIP2_TYPE]->(B) 
WITH A, count(distinct B) as unique_related_nodes
WHERE unique_related_nodes > 25 
RETURN A
```

Given you are traversing a couple of hops, it is reasonable to assume you could find you are touching a lot of nodes. A couple things to help performance:

1. Use labels and relationship types, i.e.
   `MATCH (A:LABEL_FOR_A)-[:RELATIONSHIP1_TYPE]->(obj:LABEL_FOR_MID)-[:RELATIONSHIP2_TYPE]->(B:LABEL_FOR_B)`

The middle node's label will be especially helpful in optimizing your query, but it may not be possible to know this label immediately. In which case, if needed, I would investigate the distinct labels that 'obj' has and then work from there.

2. Use `EXPLAIN` to help understand where the query can be optimized:

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (A)-[:RELATIONSHIP1_TYPE]->(obj)-[:RELATIONSHIP2_TYPE]->(B) 
WITH A, count(distinct B) as unique_related_nodes
WHERE unique_related_nodes > 25 
RETURN A
```

Enjoy!